# Why is my function returning an empty array?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to call the results of this function in my SwiftUI view:

```
class GetMessages: ObservableObject {
    let BASE_URL = "apicallurl.com"
    @Published var messages = [Timestamp]()
    func fetchMessages() {
        guard let url = URL(string: BASE_URL) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {print(error!.localizedDescription); return }
            let theData = try! JSONDecoder().decode([String: Timestamp].self, from: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.messages = Array(theData.values)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

I am testing the output with a print statement in the `onAppear`:

```
struct HomeTab: View {
  @StateObject var getMsgs = GetMessages()
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            greeting.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            messages
            Spacer()
        }
       .onAppear {
           print(getMsgs.fetchMessages())
           print(getMsgs.messages)
       }
    }.navigationBarHidden(true)
}
```

both print statements print `()` or `[]`
But when i print `print(self.messages)` in my `GetMessages` class the data prints fine.

Why is it empty in my `Hometab` view?

Comment: "...Why is it empty in my Hometab view?". It is because `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){...}` is an asynchronous function. That is, you are printing the results in `Hometab` before they are available. Read-up on async functions.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine ahh of course, makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `getMsgs.fetchMessages()` it may take some times to fetch the results. Once the results are available
the `messages` of `getMsgs` in `HomeTab` will be updated, and this will trigger a view refresh,
because it is a `@StateObject` and is "monitored" by the view.

However you should not try to `print(getMsgs.messages)` before the results are available.

So try the following sample code:

```
struct HomeTab: View {
    @StateObject var getMsgs = GetMessages()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(getMsgs.messages, id: \.self) { msg in
                    Text("\(msg)") 
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                getMsgs.fetchMessages()
                // no printing of getMsgs.messages here
            }
        }.navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```